# Finding limit with two variable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} (x^2+y^2)\ln(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) = ? $

I have tried this;

$\lim_{x\to0}(\lim_{y\to0}(x^2+y^2)\ln(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})) = 0 $

$\lim_{y\to0}(\lim_{x\to0}(x^2+y^2)\ln(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})) = 0 $

What can I do else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just switch to polar coordinates, $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, giving
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}(x^2+y^2)\ln(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})=\lim_{r\to 0}r^2\ln r = 0
$$ where we have used
$$
\lim_{r\to 0^+}r\ln r = 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
let \; u=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}
\\ then \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}(x^{2}+y^{2})ln(\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}})=\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}u^{2}ln(u)=0
$$